# Why doesn't a submit button work after table contents are replaced via ajax in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

New to Rails and even newer to Ajax. I have a page that displays a table of searchable records. I'm using partials and jQuery to update the contents of the table with the search results via ajax. This part works great, except when search results are shown, clicking the submit button does nothing, even if there are items are selected.

table partial definition:

```
<table border="1" class="pretty">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><%= sortable "name", "Name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "num_posts", "Posts" %></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<%= form_tag() do %>
<% @friends.each do |friend| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= image_tag friend.pic_url %></td>
    <td><%= friend.name %></td>
    <td><%= friend.num_posts %></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "selected_friends[#{friend.id}]" %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<%= paginate @friends %>
<br />
<%= submit_tag "Un-ignore friend(s)", :name => 'unignore_selected' %>
<% end %>
```

here's the jQuery call to render the partial via Ajax:

```
$('#datatable').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("table") ) %>');
```

and here are the jQuery methods in application.js I'm using to support this ( taken directly from railscasts, so I'm not 100% clear on what these are doing under the hood )

```
$('#datatable th a').live('click', function() {
  $.getScript(this.href);
  return false;
});

$('#data_search').submit(function() {
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
});
```

There's no activity at all in firebug or Chrome dev tools when I click a submit button after completing a search, nor are the break points on my action controllers being hit. I tried adding a jQuery function similar to "#data_search" above but this broke the buttons entirely.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried setting JavaScript breakpoints (via Firebug, Chrome dev tools, etc) on the JavaScript source inside of the submit inner function? Also it might be more helpful if you posted the actual rendered HTML table instead of just the table definition.

Comment: No, but what I did do is place alerts in the application.js file to see when / if the jquery was being hit; it was but the parameters that needed to be passed to the action controller were nil, so it would skip over the task that was supposed to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by moving the form wrapper outside the table, looks a little screwy as is.

The form in your partial does not have an action.  So when the `submit` button is pressed it isn't doing anything because it hasn't been told WHAT to do.

change

```
form_tag()
```

to

```
form_tag('/place_you_want_this_form_posted_to')
```

and that should take care of submitting the form in the first place.

The next issue is that (I assume) you also want this form to be submitted via ajax.  That's what the `$('#data_search').submit(function() {` block is doing for the first form.  It is hijacking the submit of that form and making it an ajax call instead.  You need to do the same thing for your new form.  Start by giving it an id and then do the same thing to hijack it.

```
form_tag('/place_you_want_this_form_posted_to', :id => "my_form_id")
```

The javascript hijack is the same as before

```
$('#my_form_id').submit(function() {
  $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Does having multiple submit buttons in the same form affect this solution some how? Like if you have buttons for "New, Delete selected, Ignore Selected?" Because I'm seeing an almost opposite problem now: New works in any case but "delete" and "ignore" only work when the search has been conducted...

Comment: Update: actually as long as the search button has been clicked, the buttons then respond and do the right thing when clicked, doesn't matter if there were any terms to search on in the search field...

Comment: Ah removing the hijack but following your suggestion regarding the declaration of the form tag seems to make everything work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have your form tag starting in the middle of the table.  That seems wrong. It's also probably causing your form to be replaced when the table is reloaded and that isn't a delegated submit handler so it doesn't apply to the replaced form.  I suspect that the malformed HTML is making it so nothing works for the form.  Move your form start outside the table start.

Comment: So the check_box_tags don't need to live inside the form section in order to be passed to the action controller on submit?

Comment: Just move the `form_tag` outside the top of the table, leave everything else where it is.  The weirdness is that your setup is basically `<table><form></table></form>` instead of `<form><table></table></form>`.

Comment: @BrMcMullin no, they do, but the form should contain the table rather than the other way around. Or you need to use a separate form within each table element.  Note also that Lee Quarella is correct that you need to specify the action parameter.